# Do the properties of a pedal triangle hold good when the triangle on which the pedal triangle is constructed, an obtuse an triangle?

Tags: triangles

For Example, Can we assume that the incentre of a pedal triangle is the orthocentre of the triangle on which the pedal triangle is constructed in all cases?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:Pedal triangles resultant is ex-triangle so this thing will always hold true for any type of triangle.If you want to proove put foot of perpendiculars on each side and then use basic geometry.